# jQuery ajax call not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

**[SOLVED]** I had to change the button tag to any other tag like < a > tag to call the function. Such as:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="bagadd" onclick="return all_check('add', '<?php echo $product_id;?>');"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Add To Bag</a>
```

**[Problem]**
In my project,  am sending out data from a JavaScript to PHP script using an Ajax call. I tried to look for an answer on Stackoverflow, but not success therefor I made a question.

This code is working properly on my chrome browser, but it fails when I try it out in Firefox.

**product-detail.php**

```
function all_check(action, productid){
          var product_id = productid;

          var serial = document.getElementById("showserial").value;
          var size = document.getElementById("showsize").value;
          var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

          var queryString = "";
          if(action != "") {
              switch(action) {
                  case "add":
                      queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_id+'&serial='+serial+'&quantity='+qty+'&size='+size;
                      alert(queryString);
                      break;
                  case "empty":
                      queryString = 'action='+action;
                      break;
              }
          }
          $.ajax({
              url: "ajax_action.php",
              type: "POST",
              dataType:"json", 
              data: queryString
          }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
              alert("success");
              $("#cartcount").html(data.items); //total items in cart-info element
              console.log("bla bla bla");
          });
      }
```

Here is the button which called this function:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="bagadd" onclick="return all_check('add', '<?php echo $product_id;?>');"> Add To Bag</button>
```

On button click, all_check function is called. But on Firefox, ajax call does not work.I checked it by using alert and console inside done function. I cleared cache repeatedly. But it did not work.

Anyone please kindly help me on this problem.

**EDIT 1** My firefox version is 54.0 (32-bit). 
I am using Google CDN for jQuery :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

Complete rendered html from firefox:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
      function all_check(action, productid){ // from 262 line
          var product_id = productid;
          if(document.getElementById("showsize").value==""){
             alert("Please Select size");
              return false;
          }
          else if(document.getElementById("quantity").value==""){
                  alert("Please Select Quantity");
                  document.getElementById("quantity").focus();
                  return false;
          }

          else{
              var qtyid = +document.getElementById("quantity").value;
              typeof(qtyid);
              var available = +document.getElementById("showavailable").value;
              typeof(available);
              if(qtyid > available ){
                      alert("Sorry, Available Quantity is "+ available);
                      return false;
                }
              }

          console.log("button clicked");
          var serial = document.getElementById("showserial").value;
          var size = document.getElementById("showsize").value;
          var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

          var queryString = "";
          if(action != "") {
              switch(action) {
                  case "add":
                      queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_id+'&serial='+serial+'&quantity='+qty+'&size='+size;
                      alert(queryString);
                      break;

                  case "empty":
                      queryString = 'action='+action;
                      break;
              }
          }
          $.ajax({ //make ajax request to cart_process.php
              url: "ajax_action.php",
              type: "POST",
              dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
              data: queryString
          }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
              alert("success");
              $("#cartcount").html(data.items); 
              console.log("bla bla bla");

          });

      }
      function get_availble(serial)
      {
          document.getElementById('showserial').value = serial;
          var size_n_available = document.getElementById('product_size').value;
          document.getElementById('showsize').value = size_n_available.substring(0,2) ; 
          document.getElementById('showavailable').value = size_n_available.substring(2) ; 
          alert(document.getElementById('showavailable').value);
      }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
                <a href="index.php"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div id="custom-search-input">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="button">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" width="75"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart dropdown-content" role="menu">
                                                                                   <li class=""><a href="product.php?id=01">Tote bags</a></li>
                                                                                        <li class=""><a href="product.php?id=02">Mugs</a></li>
                                                                                        <li class=""><a href="product.php?id=03">T-shirts</a></li>
                                                                                        <li class=""><a href="product.php?id=04">Throw Pillow</a></li>
                                                                                        <li class=""><a href="product.php?id=05">Notebooks</a></li>
                                                                                        <li class=""><a href="product.php?id=06">Art print</a></li>
                                                                          </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                           Items <span id="cartcount">
                                                          </span>
                         <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <div id="shopping_cart_results"></div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row top-left-message" style="background:#fff">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
            <a href="artist.php">Artist</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1  collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
            <a href="home_junctions.php">Home Junction</a>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="container">


    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">

            <div id="view-thumb">
                <img id="theImg" class="my-foto img-responsive" src="productimage/bigtea-baggin-mugs.jpg" data-large="productimage/bigtea-baggin-mugs.jpg" title="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
             <div class="productHeader container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h2>Tea baggin Mug</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">

          <p style="padding-top: 26px; padding-right:10px; font-family: Helvetica; color:#999; font-size:17px;" class="pull-right">Tk 300</p>                                    

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                    

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select id="product_size" name="product_size" class="form-control" onchange="get_availble(258)" required>
                                <option value="-1">Select Size</option>
                                                                                <option value="125">11 oz</option>
                                                                                <option value="135">15 oz</option>

                            </select>
                            <input class="form-control" id="showsize" name="showsize" placeholder="show size" type="text">
                            <input class="form-control" id="showavailable" name="showavailable" placeholder="show Quantity" type="text">
                            <input class="form-control" id="showserial" name="showserial" placeholder="show serial" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="bagadd" onclick="return all_check('add', '06020010');"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Add To Bag</button>

                        <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="forsubmit" type="hidden">

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2>Recently viewed</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="multiple-items recent_view">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/product/because-sloths-1yv-mugs.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/product/good-morning-i-see-the-assassins-have-failed-mugs.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/zoomsl-3.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/singleCartDelete.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.multiple-items').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 6,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,

        });

        $('#thumb-group a').on({
            'click': function(){

                var imgSrc = $(this).attr('data-src');

                $('#theImg').attr('src',imgSrc);
                $('#theImg').attr('data-large',imgSrc);

            }
        });
        if(!$.fn.imagezoomsl){

            $('.msg').show();
            return;
        }
         else $('.msg').hide();

        $('.my-foto').imagezoomsl({ 

             zoomrange: [1, 12],
             zoomstart: 4,
             innerzoom: true,
             magnifierborder: "none"    
        });  
    });

</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugin.js"></script>
```

This is the **ajax_action.php** file:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");
if(!empty($_POST["action"])) {
switch($_POST["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productid = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ProductID,ProductName,Price,SerialNo  FROM product_info where SerialNo='".$_POST["serial"]."'"));
            $product_image = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ImageID, ProductID,BigImage,MidImage,SmallImage,SerialNo FROM product_image
                               WHERE ProductID='".$productid[0]."' AND SerialNo='".$_POST["serial"]."'"));
            $idx = $_POST["serial"].$_POST["size"];

            $itemArray = array($idx=>array(
                                              'name'=>$productid[1],
                                              'code'=>$_POST["serial"],
                                              'image'=>$product_image[4],
                                              'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"],
                                              'price'=>$productid[2],
                                              'size'=>$_POST["size"]
                                          )
                              );

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }

    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;
}
$total_items = count($_SESSION["cart_item"]); //count total items
die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items))); //output json
```

}

?>

Comment: is your function itself being called in FF? did you check your console for any errors?

Comment: turn on javascript in your firefox browser

Comment: I checked using console, There is no error. My function does not call itself .@KarthikGanesan

Comment: How can i turn on javascript in firefox browser? @Exprator

Comment: https://www.webex.co.in/no-javascript/nojavascript-firefox.html

Comment: @NazemMahmud In questions like this, we encourage you to post more details like: version of your firefox, version of jquery, the complete html of the page. Are you sure the button is not being overlaid by some other element that prevents it from clicks?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: @Exprator javascript is enabled in my firefox browser.

Comment: @leo_ap I have edited my problem with versions. Yes, I am sure that button is not being overlaid.

Comment: @NazemMahmud Please, post the complete rendered html (copy paste it from "view source" in firefox)

Comment: @leo_ap I updated my problem according to your suggestion. Please check .

Comment: are you running this page locally? I mean, without a webserver

Comment: I ran it both locally and in a webserver. @leo_ap